# Save the hexadecimal value from a Reg_Binary key on a variable

Tags: powershell

I Need to extract the value of a REG_BINARY from the registry without make an array. Need to have the value on one line only

```
#create Object
$Contentor ="" | Select "HostGUID"

#Read the registry key with REG_BINARY
  $SyLinkScan = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink'

$Save the RegKey on the object
$Contentor.HostGUID =  $SyLinkScan.HostGUID
```

The current value that I'm getting the converted value:
PS C:\Intel\SEPReg> $Contentor.HostGUID
43
73
212
115
145
230
15
121
58
87
183
134
186
181
116
73

Need the following Result:
PS C:\Intel\SEPReg> $Contentor.HostGUID
2B49D47391E60F793A57B786BAB57449

Comment: Why do you want to?  "set-itemproperty -type binary" takes a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it back into hex like this?

```
#create Object
$Contentor ="" | Select "HostGUID"

#Read the registry key with REG_BINARY
  $SyLinkScan = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink'

$Save the RegKey on the object
$SyLinkScan.HostGUID | ForEach { 
    $Contentor.HostGUID += "{0:x}" -f $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter) class:

```
$SyLinkScan = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink'
$Contentor  = [PsCustomObject]@{ 'HostGUID' = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($SyLinkScan.HostGUID) -replace '-'}

$Contentor
```

> ```
> HostGUID                        
> --------                        
> 2B49D47391E60F793A57B786BAB57449
> ```